# Get a list of ID Attributes from an XML File C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to get a list of the Service IDs from the xml file below.

```
  <Settings>
<SomeTag>Some inner text</SomeTag>
<Services ID="Downtown Location">
    <Service ID="22923">Basic</Service>
    <Service ID="22926">Basic + 2</Service>
    <Service ID="22927">Basic + 3</Service>
    <Service ID="22928">Basic + 4</Service>
    <Service ID="22929">Basic + 5</Service> 
</Services>
<MoreTags>
    <ATag></ATag>
    <ATag></ATag>
    <ATag></ATag>
    <ATag></ATag>
</MoreTags>
</Settings>
```

I have tried several methods I found on line but each one has had some sort of problem. This was my last attempt.

```
          List<string> ServiceList = new List<string>();
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\Settings.xml");
            XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Services/Service");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                ServiceList.Add(node.Attributes["ID"].Value);
            }
            return ServiceList;
```

In this case the nodes has no items. I have tried several variations of SelectNodes but still have no items. Earlier I tried XDocument and a LINQ query. I would prefer to do it that way, but I have yet to find an example that collects the IDs.

Comment: The C# code you share will always return an empty list, as you never add anything to `ServiceList`.

Comment: Thanks Luke. I changed the name in this example and didn't change it in the loop. However, nodes is still empty. ServiceList will not contain anything because there is nothing in nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with `System.Xml.Linq`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var xmldoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(@"YOUR FILE");

    foreach (var name in xmldoc.Descendants("Services").Elements()
                        .Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, Value = x.Value, ID=x.Attribute("ID")
                       }))
    {       
       Console.WriteLine(name.ID.Value);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
22923
22926
22927
22928
22929
```

Comment: Thank you @jonathana! So your LINQ statement created an object and assigned the values of each Service Tag to that object and then assigned the attribute of the object to the list. Well, in your case wrote it to the console. I didn't see that.

Answer (score 3):

To be begin with, I believe it was a typo that you missed out the closing "Settings" Tag. To capture the ID using Linq to Xml, you could use.

```
XElement xmlNode = XElement.Load(filePath);
var result = xmlNode.Descendants("Service").Select(x=>x.Attribute("ID").Value);
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you also, Anu.  I went with the first one I saw. But I also tried your answer as well. Unfortunately I can't pick both as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to remove the leading `/` in the XPath expression in this line

```cs
            XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Services/Service");
```

to give you

```cs
            XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Services/Service");
```

An XPath expression beginning with `/` starts the search for matching elements from the root of the document.  You however have navigated to the document element and want to start the search from there.